# Optimizar Consulta en Oracle

Tags: oracle, oracle-11g

Tengo la siguiente consulta, pero al ejecutarla en oracle se demora 15 segundos, el problema es que esta consulta se realiza muchas veces y esto genera un retraso de hasta 10 o 20 minutos, alguien me podria dar una idea de como optimizarla.

```sql
SELECT LOWER(ucr.table_name),
f_to_number(SUBSTR(ucr.table_name,2,instr(ucr.table_name, '_') - 2)) 
FROM user_cons_columns ucc 
 INNER JOIN user_constraints uc ON uc.constraint_name = ucc.constraint_name 
 AND uc.constraint_type = 'R' 
 INNER JOIN user_constraints ucr ON ucr.constraint_name = uc.r_constraint_name 
 AND ucr.constraint_type = 'P' 
WHERE ucc.column_name = UPPER('c0540_rowid_nivel_educativo') AND ucc.position = 1;
```

Comment: en este caso si puedes quitar algún join sería bueno, pero más que nada cuando se trata de optimización de querys lo mejor es crear índices, si no los tienes claro... fíjate en las cláusulas where y join, además de los select y las funciones que usas ahí como lower() y f_to_number()

Comment: para poder optimizar un query, se necesita el explain plan y la descripcion de las tablas. Mas alla de eso, puede que igual tarde por la cantidad de datos que hay... sin embargo, hay algo raro en ese query. Una de las tablas, se llama asi misma, en una relacion un tanto rara a simple vista.. eso puede ser un problema

Comment: No se puede hacer un solo JOIN con `user_constraints` y usar el where para filtrar `WHERE (uc.constraint_type = 'P' OR uc.constraint_type = 'R' )?? Es que esa no es una condición del JOIN...